# $.getJSON in FireFox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am making a `WebExtension` that inputs my passwords from my web server into the `input[type='password']` fields on the webpage.

Here is the code:

```js
function getPW() {
    $.getJSON("http://mywebserver.org/p/?p=" + window.location.hostname, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            console.log("Field: " + field);
        });
    });
}

getPW();
```

which for now, just executes `console.log()`.

However, when I load this and open up the `Developer Tools`, the only output on the `Console` tab is:

```
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]
```

Here is my PHP code on my webserver:

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != null) {
        $aaJSONData = ["Password" => "mySuperSecretPassword!")];
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($aaJSONData);
    }
?>
```

and going to the URL: `http://mywebserver.org/p/?p=stackoverflow.com` in my browser shows this:

```json
{"Password":"mySuperSecretPassword!"}
```

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "PWGen",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Automatically fills out the <input type=\"password\"... /> part of the form",

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
        "id": "my@ID"
        }
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "pwgen.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have the latest `JQuery.js` in the folder.

So I'm guessing it has something to do with my `getPW()` function.

I have looked into fixing this for 3 days now, and have only just brought myself to ask a question.

Thanks :)

EDIT:
Turns out that the whole `Same Origin Policy` is blocking my request.

So is there anyway to bypass the `Same Origin Policy`?

Comment: try using the "promise interface" methods opf getJSON ... i.e., .done .fail .. .fail will let you log out failure reasons etc

Comment: When I used: `.fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
  console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: " + error)
 });`, It just logged: `getJSON failed, status error, error: `

Comment: well at least now you know you're getting a failure! Check the developer tools network tab to see what's happening with the request

Comment: `Fiddler` is saying that it isn't even connecting to my web server. There are no requests or anything.

Comment: No, you can't bypass CORS - enable cors on **your** server